# Unit Testing Angular 11 + Karma + Pug

Tags: angular, unit-testing, pug, karma-jasmine

I'm writing unit tests for angular 11 application.
In the project I'm using .pug instead of .html.

I've tried with:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack#custom-webpack-config-object
- https://github.com/StoutLLC/karma-pug-preprocessor
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-ng-pug2js-preprocessor/v/1.0.0-beta.0
  but none works.

Tests are running, but rendered pug is just a text not proper html.
Build converts files from pug to html.
In the webpack config is added pug loader.

```
"dependencies": {
  "ng-cli-pug-loader": "^0.2.2",
}


"devDependencies": {
  "pug": "^2.0.4",
  "pug-loader": "^2.4.0",
}
```

karma.conf.js

```
plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage'),
  require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
  require('karma-pug-preprocessor'),
],
files: [
  'src/**/*.pug',
],
preprocessors: {
  'src/**/*.pug': ['pug']
},
```

Answer (score 0):

After one week with this problem finally i've resolve it, i wouldn't recommend use ng-cli-pug-loader, because this library changes internal Angular code, and this always causes problems when update Angular, so for add pug to Angular, use this:

- @angular-builders/custom-webpack: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack (this library allow you change how angular is building, through webpack config file)

See this commit to add pug: https://github.com/vadjs/custom-loaders-bug/commit/24c9ce896578f7a12d79b58ff74b577b8adef339

with the above mentioned, you can run your tests and render normally yours components but you can't debug them, because there's not source map loaded on karma server, to add it you need the config for "SourceMapDevToolPLugin" you can find it on my repo (webpack.config.js) with everything

- https://github.com/NOWHEREIS/angular-pug

I hope i've helped you

Comment: Unfortunately custom webpack doesn't work with karma.
I copied your custom-loaders-bug repo and app.component.spec.ts ends with failure.
In my project there is error:  Error: Errors during JIT compilation of template for SharedPackageComponent: Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) - so that says that .pug file has not beed parse to html.